# Core Data ManagedObjectContext Notification Memory Address Changing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have am trying to observe for changes in an NSManagedObjectContext in one of my view controllers.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateData), name: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: DataManager.shared.managedObjectContext)
```

Here is my core data setup:

```
class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Store")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
        return context
    }()
}
```

I get notifications sometimes, but other times I will not. If I set the object to nil I get the notifications as expected. If I print out the managedObjectContext when I add the observer and when the notification gets called (using the nil object in the notificationObserver), they are pointing at two different managedObjectContexts. Where am I going wrong? Is there some sort of race condition on initializing the context when setting up the observer for the first time?

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your `managedObjectContext` variable code and see if it is called. More than once

Comment: It is only called once. It seems like the viewContext changes at some point after the first time getting it, so any future uses of that managedObjectContext are not pointing at the right context